# Is there an error in this problem? $\sin^4(\frac{23\pi}{12})-\cos^4(\frac{13\pi}{12})$

Tags: trigonometry

> $\sin^4(\frac{23\pi}{12})-\cos^4(\frac{13\pi}{12})$

If there were written $\frac{23\pi}{12}$ instead of $\frac{13\pi}{12}$ it could be solved as $$\begin{align}[\sin^2(\frac{23\pi}{12})+\cos^2(\frac{23\pi}{12})][\sin^2(\frac{23\pi}{12})-\cos^2(\frac{23\pi}{12})]=&\\ -[\cos^2(\frac{23\pi}{12})-\sin^2(\frac{23\pi}{12})]=& \\ -\cos(\frac{23\pi}{6})=&\\ -\cos(\frac{11\pi}{6})=&\\ -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\end{align}$$ Otherwise, there seems to be no way towards solving it.

Comment: What is the answer given by the book? Does it match up with your answer???

Comment: @Crazy Yes, it does.

Comment: @Crazy Looking below, we both turned out to be wrong Cauchy has shown that it is  right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\frac{23}{12} \pi = 2\pi - \frac{\pi}{12}$, and $\frac{13}{12} \pi = \pi + \frac{\pi}{12}$. So you have:

$$\sin^4 \frac{\pi}{12} - \cos^4 \frac{\pi}{12}$$

which surprisingly gives the same answer you reached.

Comment: Not so surprisingly since $cos(\pi-x)=-cos(x)$, and thus: $cos(\frac{13}{12}\pi)=-cos(-\frac{\pi}{12})=-cos(2\pi-\frac{\pi}{12})=-cos(\frac{23}{12}\pi)$ and $cos^2(\frac{13}{12}\pi)=cos^2(\frac{23}{12}\pi)$...

Comment: @evargalo actually, $\cos (\pi - x) = - \cos x$. Anyway the $^4$ kills it.

Comment: I fixed this with an edit, thx.